# C# Windows Form FlowLayoutPanel with AutoSize and a max amount of horizontal space to be used before stacking vertically?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I am creating a windows form in Visual Studio 2012, it has a docked and anchored FlowLayoutPanel in the centre that has Autoscroll on. I've got some groupboxes in it that I want to be arranged horizontally with any that go to the right / off the visible area of panel being arranged on the next row. This is so that if a user has the app full screen all group boxes are visible, but they can also resize it so that it's only a couple hundred pixels wide and the group boxes will all arange in a column or two. I don't mind if the panel scrolls vertically, but I don't wan't it to horizontally.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It could be that `FLowLayoutPanel.WrapsContent` has been set to False. Check that property and  ensure it is set to True.